# Back button not working as expected in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with **5** `fragments` attached to it .fragments are like `[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]` when i am pressing the back button it should come to  `fragment [1]` from  any `fargments` in `viewpager`,but the problem is i am able to come from [2]->[1],but its not responding when i am pressing BackButton from [3]->[1] its not showing any error in the `logcat` simply showing a pop up that  `Application Not Responding`.

Answer (score 1):

You should override onBackPressed() in your activity as below.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes your right but in my case i am using onKeyDown() so onBackPressed is not calling .

Comment: and [3]->[1] is not possible by using this in viewpager.By the way i have given you 1 up vote.for quick answar

Comment: @Abhijit, in your onKeyDown() method itself, you check for back key as keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK and then put the above code there.

Comment: Yes But i am not able to navigate from [3]->[1] [2]->[1] working